# Is it fine to delete Xcode completely from the Macbook?

Tags: xcode, xcode13, apple-developer

I am using xcode 13.1 for app development so far, i now want to update my xcode but i don't have enough storage in my macbook to update.

I tried updating but i don't have enough storage. can i uninstall and re install xcode and work normally without any issues?

Answer (score -2):

If you don’t have enough storage to update, I’d recommend getting a large external drive. Don’t even start using tricks to get a bit more memory out of it.

Comment: Do not answer an off topic question, please.